# Display what AVSpeechSynthesizer is showing as subtitles with Swift

Tags: swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I have an array with quotations, and am using a button to start a random quotation playing from the array.

I'm wondering, how would I have the selected random quotation also displayed in the ViewController so that people can read what the speechsynthesizer is reading?

Comment: the string you generated as random set it to the label

Comment: Add a label to your view and set `label.text = randomQuote`.

Comment: @vacawama Ok, I was able to do that by setting `let randomQuote = nTeslaQuoteArray[nTSelection]` . Now I just need to resize the Label so it always fits the content :)

Comment: @vacawama is there some way of using Subtitles.sizeToFit() so that the Label is split into 3 or more rows, instead of just "one row till infinity"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8355175/1630618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I have the selected random quotation also displayed in the ViewController so that people can read what the speechsynthesizer is reading?

The best way to highlight the vocalized word is using the `speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:` method of the **AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate protocol**.

Instead of copying and pasting the code snippet here, take a look at this [complete and useful example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) *(ObjC and Swift)* that displays the vocalized word in a bold font with the speech synthesis.

> ...is there some way of using Subtitles.sizeToFit() so that the Label is split into 3 or more rows, instead of just "one row till infinity"?

In the `Xcode Interface Builder` - `Attributes Inspector`, set the value of the label property `Lines` to 0 and adapt your constraints to get a multiline presentation.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a label to your view and and set the quote text to it

```
quoteLabel.text = randomQuote
```

To show your label on multiple rows add:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```